# SQL - Add Extra Row to Results Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a little SQL task to achieve but to be honest I have no idea how to approach it.

Consider the following table:

```
**Product ID | Product Name | Product Cat | Price | Amount Sold**
1            | product 1    | cat1        | 0.10  | 1000
2            | product 2    | cat1        | 0.50  | 10
....         | .....        | ......      | ...   | ....
500          | .....        | .......     | ...   | ....
501          | ......       | .......     | ....  | .....
....         | .......      | ......      | ..... | .....
```

For doing a sales report I have a SQL query which selects all the products, sums all the amount sold fields and calculates the total volume of sales for a product. I'm now asked to do the following:

For a number of certain product ids (f.e. 500, 501) I shall "add a row" to the result set which reads:

```
**Product ID | Product Name | Product Cat | Price | Amount Sold**
....         | .....        | ......      | ...   | ....
500          | .....        | .......     | ...   | ....
501          | ......       | .......     | ....  | .....
xxx          | Sum          | ......      | Total | Total
.....        | ........     | ........    | ..... | .....
```

How could I achieve this? Do I have to concat multiple select statements or is there a way with rollups to just group by certrain product ids?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this query used? if you use it in a reporting system, why don't you let reporting tool handle sub total?

Comment: How do you determine the ids you want to sum up?

Comment: This is something can be done in presentation layer,why in DB?

Comment: The IDs are static and determined by the sales rep. The presentation layer is the result of the db query - I know it sucks but it's just the way it is... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others in the comments have noted, it makes more sense for this kind of logic to be handled by the reporting solution itself, even if that software is something as simple as excel.

However, if I understand your requirement correctly, you could use a `UNION` of two `SELECT` queries;

Something like;

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductCat, Price, AmountSold
FROM YourTable

UNION ALL

SELECT 0, 'Sum of 1 & 2', 0, SUM(Price), SUM(AmountSold)
FROM YourTable
WHERE (ProductID = 1 OR ProductID = 2);
```

This assumes that your sums, etc will match or be convertable to the data types of the original columns. The use of `UNION ALL` performs better and prevents your new row from being removed in the unlikely event that all it's columns values match an existing row.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rudi - this works just fine! I know it's a dirty hack but the don't want it in their excel sheets, they just want to run the query and have a look. Thanks!